# Connect to Docker container running mysql on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows, docker

I am using Docker for Windows, on Windows 10 Enterprise. I am trying to connect to a container that is running mysql. I followed the instruction here https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ and I used this command to start the container `docker run --name memories -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:5.6`

if I type `docker ps` I get

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
300248b56399        mysql:5.6           "docker-entrypoint.sh"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    3306/tcp            memories
```

However I cannot figure out how to connect to this container from the host. I have tried localhost and 127.0.0.1. Each time I get an error like this

```
/* Connecting to 127.0.0.1 via MySQL (TCP/IP), username root, using password: Yes ... */
/* Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) */
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess it was more simple than I thought. I had to publish port 3306

`docker run -p 3306:3306 --name memories -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:5.6`

Comment: How to persistent the MySQL data? maybe you need to enable docker volume

Comment: @yuzhen I use smth like this in my `docker-compose.yml` file: `volumes:
      - ./etc/infrastructure/dev/mysql:/etc/mysql/conf.d:ro
      - ./mysqldb:/var/lib/mysql`

Comment: This was my fist time using docker on windows and I though the ports would be automaticaly publisehd/exposed to the host, it wasn't. So, if anyone happpen to step on the same issue, check if during the settup you have really seted up the ports, since lefting the field in blank will not expose the port. (might be obviously now that I know, but it wasnt as a begginer)

Answer (score 0):

## Docker MySQL and phpMyAdmin containers on Windows 10

Persist MySQL volume in “C:\mysql” folder.

Set username and password for MySQL database. Create database.

```
docker run --name mysql-server_v2 -d --restart=unless-stopped -v C:\mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootp -e MYSQL_USER=user1 -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=user1p -e MYSQL_DATABASE=projectX mysql:5.7.29
```

Connect **phpMyAdmin** and accessing it with localhost:8080

```
docker run --name phpmyadmin_v2 -d --link mysql-server_v2:db -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

src: https://devwl.pl/docker-setup-mysql-with-phpmyadmin-on-windows10-11/